# Bounty and a somewhat useful answer with the real solution in comment - I must not edit it?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have added a bounty to a question where no answer existed. Now someone answered, but the answer does not fit my software setup. After some clarification, I got a good (but very short) answer in the comments section of the original answer.

Now I tried editing the answer quite to make it more useful for others by extending it. But the edit was rejected by two reviewers. This is my edit proposal:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20052153

I wanted to edit the answer because the author should get the bounty AND the answer should (at least in my opinion) be as useful as possible. But the reviewers used the reason "should be a comment or an answer". Well, sure, I could create a new answer myself. But does that make sense? I would create an own answer but payout the bounty to the other answer (because I want to thank the original answerer) .

This said, I don't know how to continue now. The whole situation does not make any sense for me. Can someone tell me how to handle this the **intended** way?

Comment: Weel, when suggesting edits it's really important to have a good description, to make the editors understand your reason to make such a substantial change. Also, you can ask the answerer to edit their answer to include all the cases.

Comment: Well, yes, I could ask the original author to edit it the way it helped me (which is probably harder for him/her than for me who already coded down a working solution). But ok, maybe it makes sense to create an own answer as one handles one special case and the other another one. For that to answer, I don't know the rules and/or best practices for "answer separation" good enough.

Comment: @Adinia Even so, how would something that substantial be fit for a "comment"... If anything it drastically changed the intent of the answer, which would make sense, but otherwise the reject reasons were kind of lame...

Comment: Well, at this point I would say to make sure to give him the green check mark on his answer.  As his answer+comment did it for you.

Comment: Always relevant: [What should be done with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117251/164088)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edits to someone else's answer typically should never add new code. Doing so would give the impression to readers that the answer author is the one who wrote that code. The rejection reason for this is typically "Clearly conflicts with the author's intent":

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

But in your case, you were trying to respond to the author by indicating you had alternate code that worked thanks to their answer and ensuing comments. Thus, you received two rejections for the "attempt to reply" rejection reason:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

In this case, what I would have recommended was editing the author's comment into the question (with a clear edit description indicating that you are just adding OP's comment to OP's post). Then, you should provide your own answer (Community Wiki if you like; this will prevent you from gaining reputation and indicate somewhat that the answer is not entirely "yours") with the code you tried to add to the existing answer.

As far as indicating thanks or helpfulness, you can then apply the bounty to the answerer to indicate that their answer (and any ensuing comment) was most helpful in you finding a solution.

Comment: I think that this is almost what I did now (just that I forgot about the Community Wiki feature). At least I now better understand the reason for the rejection. Thank you for the clarification :-)